# Clear contents of a Text File

Tags: c, windows, winapi, text-files

I am working on a sever/client applicataion. I want to maintain information of all active clients in a text file named "Information.txt".
I update this text file after every 3 seonds. So, I want the text file to clear all of its contents after every 3 seconds without deleting the file.
Is there any way to do it ? :(
I don't want to use freopen().

Comment: to use `fopen` instead is ok?

Comment: Yes, using fopen is not a problem :) I just don't want to use freopen().

Comment: close and open with "w". rather "w+"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

> fopen(filename, flag)

Open your file with flag= "w" or "wb" and it will be cleared

Comment: Glad! Took me whole day to search things over the internet and you solved the problem in few minutes. Thank you so much :)

Comment: but now, if I open a file with "w" flag, I am unable to read the data from this file into a buffer. :( what could be the reason? :(

Comment: it will clear all the data when you open it. read http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html

Comment: If you want to read it, then open in read mode. and again use it in w or wb mode to clear. Best solution is to open the file in read mode and read the data, store it to another file then replace the file with newone.

Answer (score 3):

A problem with clearing the file periodically is that if your process crashes after the file has been cleared but before it has been written, you lose data: the old data is gone, but the new data is not there yet.

A common approach to this problem is to create a new file, writing it, and then moving the new file to replace the old one. This way you always have a file, and sometimes (for very brief periods of time) you have two files.

Answer (score 1):

Just open the file with `fopen` and setting the flag to **w** or **w+** or **wb**

From [fopen man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen)

> **w**
>
> Truncate file to zero length or create text file for writing. The
>   stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.
>
> **w+**
>
> Open for reading and writing. The file is created if it does not
>   exist, otherwise it is truncated. The stream is positioned at the
>   beginning of the file.